# Implement a function that takes a list of items and a callback

Tags: javascript, function, callback

I am so new in Java Script. I have to solve some exercise but I don't even know how to do that( Please help me somebody.

Implement a function called countWhich() which will take in a list of items and a callback, and it will return the number of elements which return a truthy value from the callback function.

```
function countWhich(list, cb) {


}
```

Examples of output:

- countWhich([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], function(num) { return (num > 4); }) returns 1
- countWhich(["apple", "banana", "cherry"], function(fruit) { return fruit[0] === "a"; }) returns 1
- countWhich([10, 20, 30, 40, 50], function(num) { return num % 7 === 0; }) returns 0
- countWhich(["apple", "banana", "cherry"], function(fruit) { return fruit.length > 5; }) returns 2
- countWhich([], function(x) { return x > 10 }) returns 0
- countWhich("This should fail", function(word) { return /i/.test(word); }) returns false

Comment: something creazy in this exercise...

Comment: @AntonPegov I don't even understand how can I get such output ...

Comment: At least one of these examples has a nonsensical output based on the requirements.  Also, this site is to help people solve problems **with the code they wrote**, not solve problems **by writing code from scratch**.  Given the examples don't make sense, this is definitely something that should be discussed with the course administrator.

Answer (score 0):

I have already solved it)

```
function countWhich(list, cb) {
  var count = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if (cb(list[i]) === true) {
      count += 1;
    }
  }
  return count;
}
```